# SQL locking occurring and then hangs up entire office

Tags: sql, database, locking

I starting at a new company and am a web applications developer. So I am not a DB Guru, but have worked with it my entire career obviously being a developer. The company keeps randomly getting a locking issues, that then holds up the internal application an locks everyone. They then have to kill a service to correct the issue, and free up SQL. Now, I am wondering if when a query occurs, if it is a long query and the user thinks the system froze, so they close out the app, will that freeze up SQL? Basically, if the lock query is in the middle of a query, and the application who called the query just does a hard exit, does SQL then dispose that thread, or does it freeze it, in return hanging up next threads that are to run after that lock completes?

I have done in prior companies where if a table is currently locked, we alert the end user so they are aware of this and do not think it is an error. Wondering if we should do the same here?

Thanks

Comment: That depends on the database and how the query was sent.  Some databases will cancel a query when the session that created it closes.

Comment: That is what I was wondering. What information should I look into to see if this is or is not occurring? Also thanks for your help.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? ("SQL" is a query language, not a specific database product)

Comment: SQL Server i think 2012